# is there a way to call method with n arguments, from list of fields in Java

Tags: java

I need to call a third party method, lets say, that is like below

```
// Definition
public method1(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, ..... So ON){
...
}

// call
method1("a","b","c"....);
```

I got a line which is delimited eg: x1,x2,x3...xn.
How could i form the method using the line now.?

Suppose if i got any input as this "sr1,sr2,sr3,sr4....sr"

How can i Call the method as method1("sr1","sr2"...."srn")
We should not pass array or list. We should pass individual field to the method.

Comment: Does the method definition use a wildcard?

Comment: check `variable argument function`

Comment: The third party method uses whatever the arguments i passed to construct another object. If i passed list, then it goes in as object with list.